# Powering DC 5v 120w from AC 110v

Tags: power-supply, 5v

I would like to power a large set of LED strips. Doing my calculation, at maximum output, I would require 120w at 5v. I am relatively new to electronics, so please excuse the noob question.

In my research, I have found significant limitations in what I am trying to do. I have not found a wallwart capable of doing this. I have also found that using voltage regulators will produce too much heat, and would be dangerous. I have been searching transformers, but I am not finding this much help either.

I have found, however, a 110 V converter switching power supply that is rated at 350w. I suppose this would be what I need to use. I can only find this on eBay or AliExpress. Using something like that direct from China makes me nervous. This will be installed in my house.

Could anybody please point me in the right direction? I am looking for theory, as well as safety information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could possibly use a cheap power supply from a computer.  Any reasonable supply should be able to provide plenty of current on the 5V rail, and they are relatively easy to find.  Jack's answer works as well.

Comment: Cirka 2004 ATX power supplies had a butload of grunt on the 5 V rail. Later installments moves to 12 V power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this, with tradeoffs for efficiency, ease of design, cost, space etc...  But if you're new to electronics, then consider buying something like this:

[LS150-5 - AC/DC Enclosed Power Supply (PSU), Compact, 1 Outputs, 130 W, 5 V, 26 A - from Farnell UK](http://uk.farnell.com/tdk-lambda/ls150-5/psu-enclosed-5v-26a-150w/dp/1657459)

This has the advantage that all the (dangerous) mains electronics is done for you and bundled up in a box, so there's less chance for mistakes. This particular one is from the UK, but you should be able to find one wherever you live.  The trick is not to look at ebay or amazon, but at an actual electronics supplier. In the UK, that would be Farnell, Rapid, Mouser or RS. In the US, you might look at Digikey.

Comment: I found your suggestion on Digikey https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/tdk-lambda-americas-inc/LS150-5/285-1817-ND/1918828. I also found a similar one on Ali Express https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC5V-30A-150W-LED-driver-Switch-Power-Supply-Transformer-For-Led-Strip-Light-Adapter/32605333888.html?spm=2114.13010208.99999999.333.PCGdj9. I assume that the Digikey one is better, as it is documented.  The price on Digikey is $61CAD plus tax and shipping, vs $22CAD including tax and shipping from Ali Express. Would the difference be worth it?

Comment: Neither digikey nor AliExpress make power supplies.  Digikey will only import safe and legal ones. The AliExpress one may be safe and legal, or may not.  If you have the knowledge, experience, and free time to chase it up, find the manufacturer, and verify it is OK, then you can save some money. If not, then I would stick with Digikey (or farnell, or newark etc.).

Comment: A final choice that I have neglected it an LED driver like this one: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5V-100W-waterproof-IP67-Switching-power-supply-20A-100W-Driver-Adapter-Transformer-100-240V-AC-Power/32796123113.html?spm=2114.13010208.99999999.275.I8Q4zA.  The rated power is lower than I require, but is something like this adequate and safe?  I could not find them on Digikey.  The LED drivers I found there all seem to not have constant voltage, which I believe is important for the APA102 strips (I might be mistaken here, yet again).

Comment: I think I will go with your recommendation via Digikey. I read the product information, but am confused about a warning I read "This power supply has a possibility for hazardous voltage to appear at output terminal depending on the type of failure. The outputs of these products must be earthed in the end equipment to maintain SELV.    If the outputs are not earthed, they must be considered hazardous and must not be made user accessible." Would you be able to explain what this means I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

120W at 5V means you need a power supply that can put out 24A.  That's a big current - more than any wall wart can produce.  So you'd need a proper cased power supply, as Jack B suggested.

Also be aware that 24A is a **big** current.  It's unlikely to work if you try to connect all the lighting strips end-to-end.  Most likely, you'd need several wires from the power supply to small groups of LED strips.  Check the LED manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: Yes, 24A is indeed big, that is the reason for thinking very seriously about safety.  I was planning on having each 1m strip of LEDs come off a large cable from the power supply. I am now wondering if getting 2 or 3 5v 10A walwarts would be safer than just one high powered 5v power supply.  Any opinion about this?

Comment: @Fed If youre going to run multiple thinner gauge wires to the strips, it would be wise to add fuses to limit the current to something the wires can handle.  That might not have to be one fuse per wire, though.  Several smaller supplies would reduce that risk, especially if you get decent ones that shut down on overload.